# @autowired field and also @autowired constructor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a spring MVC application. I have a bean which is wired as a singleton and also a field which is also autowired but is of request scope.
For example:

```
class Hello {

  @Autowired
  BDepend b; // this is defined as a request scope bean

  @Autowired
  public Hello(ADepend a){
  }
}
```

Here my class Hello is a singleton but BDepend is a request scope object. 
How does spring handle right instance of Bdepend for each of the request since Hello is a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

By default you will have runtime exception at application sturtup. Something like this:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'b': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;`

To use request scope objects inside of some singleton you need to obtain a fresh instace each time from application context. You can do it:

- using application context directly

  ```
  class Hello {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Autowired
    public Hello(ADepend a){
    }

    public useB(){
       BDepend instance = ctx.getBean(BDepend.class);
       instance.doSomething();
    }
  }
  ```
- or get a fresh instance via `javax.inject.Provider`.

  ```
  class Hello {

    @Autowired
    private Provider<BDepend> provider;        

    @Autowired
    public Hello(ADepend a){
    }

    public useB(){
       BDepend instance = this.provider.get();
       instance.doSomething();
    }
  }
  ```
- or declare scoped proxy for this bean:

  ```
  @Component
  @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  class BDepend {

  }

  class Hello {

    @Autowired
    private BDepend b;        

    @Autowired
    public Hello(ADepend a){
    }

    public useB(){
       b.doSomething();
    }
  }
  ```
- or use scoped proxies system wide

  ```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.beans" scoped-proxy="targetClass" />
  ```

Personally I prefer second option (`javax.inject.Provider`): it is clear from the code that your bean has different scope.

Comment: Surprisingly spring is handling this correctly.. I see that there is singleton object of my class and the right instance of BDepend for each of my request. I wanted to know how spring is handling this.

Comment: May be you use your bean via scoped proxy. Are you sure that your Hello instance is singleton? Which version of spring do you use?